# What would be the most appropriate command for Mac OS to use in this scenario?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, command-line

I'm trying to solve it, but I can't. Could they help?

_ = system(' **[ *the Mac OS command here* ]** ')

```
from os import system, name  
    
    def pause_on_any_os():
    
     # mac
     if name == 'macos':
       _ = system('[the Mac OS command here]') 
    
     # linux            
     elif name == 'linux':
       _ = system('read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key')
    
     # windows
     else:
       _ = system('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe','/c PAUSE')
```

Comment: But you wouldn't call a program to pause when `time.sleep` already exists. Python replaces this type of thing.

Comment: Or, better `input("Press any key to continue")`.

Comment: Perhaps print the prompt `print("Press any key to continue", end="")` followed by `sys.read(1)`.

Comment: @tdelaney

the sleep() need a argument
 
but this `input('')` show pressed keys.

I am looking for `sys.read(1)` in Python docs

Comment: oops, typo on my part. `sys.stdin.read(1)`. stdin is a file like object that reads console input and it has a read method.

Comment: hey @tdlaney

I found this solution

That no show any key that was pressed by user

`os.system("""bash -c 'read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."'""")`


sourcer:

https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/280633/How-do-I-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key

Comment: Another option is in the `getpass` module which gets passwords without echoing the data to the screen. You could repurpose it. `getpass.getpass("Press <return> to continue ")`. Reading stdin tends to be line buffered, so its frequently triggered when someone hits return, not on every character. Reading character by character can differ between linux like systems and windows.

Comment: In the linux world, you can use terminal controls to disable echoing. I think that to do the same thing in windows you need to turn to the win32 terminal commands. Both have complications. if `getpass` is close enough for you, then less work.

Comment: getpass.getpass("Press <return> to continue ")

that works so good to!! 

Thanks a lot for you time!!!!!!!!!!